# Can the PIN-input be modified to not display the last character?

Tags: security, 4.2-jelly-bean

Since today I have a new Nexus 4, with android 4.2.2. But when I type in my PIN, it always displays the last typed character in the input field. I think that is quite the security risk.  On my old android phone (gingerbread) I was able to turn this behavior off. However, I cannot find this option on my new device. So, is there such an option, and if so, where can I find it?

Answer (score 2):

Start the **Settings** app. Choose **Security** from the **Personal** section. The option you want is called **Make passwords visible**.